# How to generate JUnit XML reports in Codename One?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, codenameone

From the documentation of Codename One, we see that there is a class for generating JUnit XML reports - [com.codename1.testing.JUnitXMLReporting](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/testing/JUnitXMLReporting.html). However, I do not know how to actually use it to create reports. Where in build.xml should I tell the class that will generate the report? Or if this is not the way this class is used, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been quite a while but I think it worked as:

```
TestReporting.setInstance(new JUnitXMLReporting());
```

I don't think there is a command line at this time.

Comment: I put this in the prepare method of a unit test. Is there a way to enable this for all tests?

Comment: I'm not sure, you can file an RFE but I don't know if we'll be able to schedule it for 3.6 as it's already pretty packed.